# What does it mean to get such a high TCP packet

Tags: networking, security

In a typical home network setup containing only a modem & one pc (freshly installed with windows 10, checksum validated), no wireless. The speed download limit is 2 Mbits. How could I get such a high signal as in the following photo:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/T3oTa]

What does that mean?

In addition to that I logged an event of admin login without login time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities here.  There may be others, but these are the most likely possibilities -

1. Your ISP may be shaping traffic in such a way that it allows for bursts at higher speed - this is quite common as it makes loading web pages snappier, and is more efficient for the whole network.  Looking at the time immediately preceding the spike there is a dip in traffic - and seems to happen to a greater or lesser degree each time its preceded by a drop in traffic so this is the most probable answer.  (The actual line speed to your ISP is most likely greater then 2 megabit, its most likely a cap implemented in software in the router).
2. The additional traffic could be coming from within your LAN.  The maximum speed of your LAN would most likely be at least 100 megabits per second, so if there is communication with other devices (eg a network printer - even if the printer is on wireless, or file-sharing with another device) you will be able to exceed the 2 megabit.
3. Your ISP has some traffic which is not shaped.  Some ISP's do this as a bonus for some traffic, or because the traffic is within their network and because of network design its simply easier not to rate-limit this traffic.

Comment: Extension of (2): maybe it is LAN traffic between the PC and the modem.

Comment: @mere3ortal this is, of-course possible - however unless the modem is a router/fileserver there would generally not be a significant amount of traffic sent from (as opposed to through) a router.

Comment: @davidgo this is a decent answer. +10 to you sir

Comment: also I'd like to add that there is log like the following image 
https://imgur.com/a/oUGJm

Comment: Not sure what that screenshot is trying to tell us.  I'm pretty sure the number of people logged on (locally) to your system is relevant to your ability to burst past your maximum Internet speed.

Comment: I am using Psloggedon to track user login event & I find that someone else is logged in with admin account PAT however I wasn't logged in. in addition to that the loggin time was erased which could mean it is an attack. here is a full image
https://imgur.com/a/YB38Z

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert - but this would be a different question, not part of the one you asked.